# Recreating previously deleted AKS with Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I have a resource group on Azure which contains several resources that were originally created with a Terraform script. Somehow I deleted the Kubernetes cluster resource and also reset the TF state. My intention was recreating this AKS module, but now when I run the terraform script pipeline I get the error that the resource already exists for the following resources:

**module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principle_policy: Creating... module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.users_policy: Creating... module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.readers_policy: Creating... module.rg.azurerm_resource_group.rg: Creating... module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.readers_policy: Creating...**

My question is, how could I recreate the AKS cluster while keeping the current resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By any chance did you have versioning enabled or a snapshot of the state file? I would suggest restoring the state if possible. And If that's not possible then you have to import those resources ( already available ). The good thing is that Terraform `> 1.5` import is not as cumbersome as it used to be. Refer to https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import  Please add some code in future if you need help with import :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have deleted the resources from state file, one possible way is to import the same resource via terraform import command like below:-

```
terraform import module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principle_policy <existing_key_vault_id>/accesspolicies/<policy_id>
terraform import module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.users_policy <existing_key_vault_id>/accesspolicies/<policy_id>
terraform import module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.readers_policy <existing_key_vault_id>/accesspolicies/<policy_id>
terraform import module.rg.azurerm_resource_group.rg /subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group_name>
```

Another  way is to get the terraform configuration of your existing state file and then add terraform configuration code blocks to match the existing state.

Check existing state like below:-

```
terraform state list
```

[image]

Run terraform show command to check the existing configuration and add the code block of AKS that matches this configuration state.

```
terraform show
```

[image]

After creating a configuration code for missing or already existing resources like I created one configuration block for NetWorkWatcherRG in my code and imported it in my tfstate :-

[image]

**Added the configuration block:-**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "NetworkWatcherRG" {
    name = "NetworkWatcherRG"
    location = var.resource_group_location
  
}
```

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Quickstart: Create an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster by using Terraform - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/quick-kubernetes-deploy-terraform?tabs=azure-cli)